# Automapper to work with nested base class with two sub types to flattened Dto

Tags: c#, automapper

Based on all the examples I've seen, I expected to have this solved by now, but can't quite get the mapping to work for some reason.  I keep getting a `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` exception.  Using Automapper 4.2.1

Here are my classes:

```
public class Schedule
{
  public ScheduleData ScheduleData { get; set; }
}

// Base type
public abstract class ScheduleData {}

// Sub Types
public class ActionItemScheduleData : ScheduleData {}
public class FormScheduleData : ScheduleData {}
```

Here's the mapping.  I went with an `AfterMap()` approach, and broke out the mappings by type.  I didn't think I had to do this, but I got the above error when I just mapped the base type.  Even with this approach with the if/else, I still get the error.  Is this due to my version of Automapper?

```
public class ScheduleMapper : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<ActionItemScheduleData, ScheduleDto>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.ActionDescription));

        CreateMap<MobileFormScheduleData, ScheduleDto>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.Description));

        CreateMap<Schedule, ScheduleDto>(MemberList.Destination)
            .AfterMap((s, d) => 
            {
                if (s.ScheduleData is MobileFormScheduleData)
                {
                    Mapper.Map((MobileFormScheduleData) s.ScheduleData, d);
                }
                else
                {
                    Mapper.Map((ActionItemScheduleData) s.ScheduleData, d);
                }
           });

    }
}
```

Here's where I call it:

```
 var scheduleDto = mapper.Map<ScheduleDto>(schedule);
```

Comment: Show mapping code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you serious?  desired behaviour is: don't get an exception.

Comment: I got the same problem, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by following code:

```
CreateMap<Schedule, ScheduleDto>().ForMember(t => t.ScheduleData, opt => opt.Ignore()).AfterMap((s, t, c) => 
            {
                t.ScheduleData = c.Mapper.Map<MobileFormScheduleData, ScheduleDto>((MobileFormScheduleData)s.ScheduleData )
           });
```